# Is <string> automatically included when including <sstream>

Tags: c++, string, include

This question is clearly for example codes. Many times, when showing `std::stringstream` examples I think if I need to explicitly add `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<sstream>` header might or might not include the `<string>` header. Ultimately it is implementation dependent. You should **explicitly** include the `<string>` header when working with strings and not rely on implementation dependent *free-rides*.

Comment: Just a note on terminology: this is not implementation defined. It is, indeed, implementation dependent. Implementation defined is a term of art in the language definition, and when some behavior is implementation defined it means that a conforming implementation must document what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, no.

But everything required to make a `std::stringstream` work is included by `#include <sstream>`.

If you want to instantiate a `std::string` of your own, `#include <string>`.